# Analysis math irrational proof

Tags: analysis, factoring

How come $q = \frac{2p+2}{p+2}$ turns into $q^2 - 2 = \frac{2(p^2-2)}{(p+2)^2}$ I've tried factoring, square both sides, but I cant see it. this sample belongs to Rudin Analysis book

Comment: $q^2 - 2 = \frac{(2p+2)^2 - 2(p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2}$. Now expand the squares in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks daniel, did you add (-2) in both sides?

Comment: With more steps: $q^2 - 2 = \frac{(2p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2} - 2 = \frac{(2p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2} - 2\frac{(p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2} = \frac{(2p+2)^2 - 2(p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2}$.

Comment: God, finally I can remember that step, thanks so much man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
$$q^2 = \frac{4p^2 + 8p + 4}{p^2 + 4p + 4}$$
$$q^2 - 2 = \frac{4p^2 + 8p + 4 - (2p^2 + 8p + 8)}{p^2 + 4p + 4} = \frac{2p^2 - 4}{p^2 + 4p + 4} = \frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p+2)^2}.$$